# Mysql limit subquery not principal query

Tags: mysql, opencart

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT pov.product_id
 ,  (SELECT AVG(r1.rating) AS total 
       FROM oc_review r1 
      WHERE r1.product_id = pov.product_id 
        AND r1.status = 1 
      GROUP 
         BY r1.product_id) AS rating
 ,  (SELECT price 
       FROM oc_product_special ps 
      WHERE ps.product_id = pov.product_id 
        AND ps.customer_group_id = 1
        AND (
              (ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
          AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())
            ) 
        ORDER 
           BY ps.priority ASC
          ,  ps.price ASC 
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS special 
 FROM oc_product_option_value pov 
 LEFT 
 JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
   ON pov.product_id = p2c.product_id
 LEFT 
 JOIN oc_product p 
   ON p.product_id = pov.product_id 
 LEFT 
 JOIN oc_product_special ps 
   ON ps.product_id = pov.product_id
WHERE p2c.category_id = 62 
  AND pov.option_id = 13 
  AND pov.quantity > 0 
ORDER 
   BY p.date_added DESC 
LIMIT 54
```

If i don't use LIMIT, my query has more than 200 results, but when i limit for 54 results, my query has 21 results. Why? How can i do to limit results after validate conditions from tables, not total from 1st select?

Comment: can you format it to make it readable?

Comment: This is Opencart database, if I am not wrong! Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ? Maybe there is a better solution around. Too many subqueries wont scale well when you reach (let's say 100k products), especially when all the tables of OC are MyISAM

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes, it's opencart. I made an filter by options and i want to show in page only 54 of item selected. If i don't use limit, it show all item from category selected, if i use limit, it show only 21 item, depend of category, if i select other category it show more ore less items.

Comment: @MariaPopovici You will have duplicate product_id(s) coming because `product_option_value` table will have multiple options_value_id for a same product_id. Use Distinct at the beginning and compare results.

Comment: Also, optimize it further by doing `inner join` with oc_product and oc_product_to_category instead of `left join`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you are awesome! Thank you, work it now, and this solved another problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Opencart Database. You have multiple issues with your attempt.

- `product_option_value` will have multiple `option_value_id` values for a `product_id`. You need to use `Distinct` to get unique product(s).
- You dont need to do Left join on `oc_product` since a `product_option_value_id` cannot exist without `product_id` in `oc_product` table.
- Since you are searching on `category_id`, you can also change your `left join` on `oc_product_to_category` table to `inner join`.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pov.product_id
 ,  (SELECT AVG(r1.rating) AS total 
       FROM oc_review r1 
      WHERE r1.product_id = pov.product_id 
        AND r1.status = 1 
      GROUP 
         BY r1.product_id) AS rating
 ,  (SELECT price 
       FROM oc_product_special ps 
      WHERE ps.product_id = pov.product_id 
        AND ps.customer_group_id = 1
        AND (
              (ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
          AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())
            ) 
        ORDER 
           BY ps.priority ASC
          ,  ps.price ASC 
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS special 
 FROM oc_product_option_value pov 
 INNER 
 JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
   ON pov.product_id = p2c.product_id
 INNER  
 JOIN oc_product p 
   ON p.product_id = pov.product_id 
 LEFT 
 JOIN oc_product_special ps 
   ON ps.product_id = pov.product_id
WHERE p2c.category_id = 62 
  AND pov.option_id = 13 
  AND pov.quantity > 0 
ORDER 
   BY p.date_added DESC 
LIMIT 54
```